# How to solve XMLHttpRequest error on azure published Blazor Apps

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a couple of Blazor Web Assembly Appps published to Azure App Service. Some in .NET Core 3.1 and some in .NET 5 I noticed when they are published to Azure, the console shows this error message

> blazornet5spinnerstest.azurewebsites.net/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://app-directory.s3.amazonaws.com/hootlet/launched-app-directory-apps.json' from origin 'https://blazornet5spinnerstest.azurewebsites.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I don't see that message when testing locally. I already tried setting up cors allowing everything, but the errors keeps showing in the published app.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: you need to setup cors

Comment: @Sajeetharan
I thought so too, but not even that worked, I even tried allowing everything when setting up CORS and issue still happens when published to Azure.

Comment: [Try to set cors on portal, like my pic.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxHVc.png)

Comment: These several blazor projects, you can set up by this way in app services. If you have any progress, please @ let me know.

Comment: Do you have some sort of Hootlet browser extension installed that might be making that request?

Comment: @DanielRoth forgot to response, indeed, Hootsuite was messing up with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to Hootsuite extensions installed in chrome.
Removed the extension and it fixed the error.